# copy of a n-tree

Tags: python, tree, copy

I've a little question about the best way to copy a n-tree. I wrote a class for the tree where each node has a pointer to his father and a list of pointer to his children. I'm thinking of a recursive method like a Depth-first search approach..

Thanks for your advices

N.

FYI: I'm coding in python

edit >

I found the solution by myself :

```
def copySubTree(self):
  if(len(self.child)==0):
     copy = Treenode(name=self.name,Mh=self.Mh,Mv=self.Mv)
     return copy
  else:
     copy = Treenode(name=self.name,Mh=self.Mh,Mv=self.Mv)
     for i in self.child:
        x = i.copySubTree()
        copy.addChild(x)
     return copy
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it. That way, this question will not come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself :

```
def copySubTree(self):
  if(len(self.child)==0):
     copy = Treenode(name=self.name,Mh=self.Mh,Mv=self.Mv)
     return copy
  else:
     copy = Treenode(name=self.name,Mh=self.Mh,Mv=self.Mv)
     for i in self.child:
        x = i.copySubTree()
        copy.addChild(x)
     return copy
```